# Puppeteer / Node.js: Can I run a script non-stop 24/7?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macros, puppeteer

I have a macro (Macro Recorder), which runs 24/7 without pause.
I need to view an item in one tab, order a specific quantity in another tab, write a message and repeat.

Can I achieve this result with Puppeteer?
What happens if I do not the close browser (because I don't need to)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to run puppeteer 24/7 without any problems. Simply don't close the browser and keep using it. I have run puppeteer instances myself for weeks without any issues. You can see some statistics of one of the runs [here](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster/issues/25#issuecomment-423295160).

The only thing you need to watch out for is error and memory handling. You need to make sure your script does not crash due to some minor JavaScript error. Additionally, you need to clean up any memory (by closing the page or even the browser) that might be leaked due to other kind of errors (network errors, SSL errors, timeouts, ...). See the linked run above to see a full list of errors that might happen during crawling process.

#### puppeteer-cluster: Pool of puppeteer instances

Depending on the complexity of your use case you might want to use the library [puppeteer-cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster) (disclaimer: I'm the author), which takes care of these kind of problems and also gives you a simple monitoring overview, which is very handy when running a task for a long time.